# Order by random number not working in Impala

Tags: sql, impala

When I run this in Hue against an Impala data source, I get an unexpected result

```
select id, rand(unix_timestamp(now())) as ord
from (
  select 1 as id union select 2 union select 3 union select 4
) x
order by ord
```

I'd expect to get the rows ordered in a random order by whatever comes up in the ord column.  Instead, I always get 3, 4, 1, 2 with numbers in ord that aren't in order:

```
id  ord
3   0.8899110606358904
4   0.3766916056055071
1   0.09029531483086539
2   0.7446466436351866
```

So, what part of ORDER BY does Impala not understand?  Or what am I missing?

Comment: look at the jira issue https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IMPALA-397

Comment: Any suggestions for a workaround?  Is there a "less random" function I can use, as we just need to avoid any human-discernible pattern in the row order--we don't need true randomness.  I suppose I could invent my own, but I'm guessing there's a better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that [Impala 2.8 and lower has this bug](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IMPALA-397).  This is claimed to be fixed in Impala 2.9, but I haven't tested it yet.

In the meantime, since I don't need very robust randomness, I just used:

```
order by mod((((unix_timestamp() + MY_ID_COLUMN) * 7621) + 1), 32768)
```

(There is a definite pattern to such results, but it is probably good enough to fool a casual observer.)

Thanks to Vamsi Prabhala for pointing me in the right direction.